# Start new process on __init__ (for TCP listener - server)

Tags: python, tcp, multiprocessing, server

I'm trying to run new process for each new instance of class `Server`. Each `Server` instance should listen on specific port. I have this (simplified) code so far: [source](https://gist.github.com/micktwomey/606178)

```
class Server(object):

    def handle(connection, address):

        print("OK...connected...")
        try:
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(1024)
                if data == "":
                    break
                connection.sendall(data)
        except Exception as e:
           print(e)
        finally:
            connection.close()

    def __init__(self, port, ip):

        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip
        self.socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.socket.listen(1)

        while True:
            print("Listening...")
            conn, address = self.socket.accept()
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Pmu.handle, args=(conn, address))
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()

s1 = Server(9001,"127.0.0.1")
s2 = Server(9002,"127.0.0.1")
```

But when I run this script only first server **s1** is running and waiting for connection. How to make both servers listening at the same time?

Comment: Try different ports.

Comment: @JonathanDavies I'm using different ports (9001 and 9002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current server is effectively a [SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) that enters a tight loop in its `__init__`, foerever accepting new connections, and creating a new child process for each incoming connection.

The problem is that `__init__` never returns, so only one server gets instantiated, one socket gets bound, and only one port will accept new requests.

A common way of solving this type of problem is to move the accept loop into a worker thread.  This code would look something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import socket

class Server(object):

    def handle(self, connection, address):
        print("OK...connected...")
        try:
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(1024)
                if data == "":
                    break
                connection.sendall(data)
        except Exception as e:
           print(e)
        finally:
            connection.close()
            print("Connection closed")

    def accept_forever(self):
        while True:
            # Accept a connection on the bound socket and fork a child process
            # to handle it.
            print("Waiting for connection...")
            conn, address = self.socket.accept()
            process = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=self.handle, args=(conn, address))
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()

            # Close the connection fd in the parent, since the child process
            # has its own reference.
            conn.close()

    def __init__(self, port, ip):
        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.socket.listen(1)

        # Spin up an acceptor thread
        self.worker = threading.Thread(target=self.accept_forever)
        self.worker.daemon = True
        self.worker.start()

    def join(self):
        # threading.Thread.join() is not interruptible, so tight loop
        # in a sleep-based join
        while self.worker.is_alive():
            self.worker.join(0.5)

# Create two servers that run in the background
s1 = Server(9001,"127.0.0.1")
s2 = Server(9002,"127.0.0.1")

# Wait for servers to shutdown
s1.join()
s2.join()
```

Note one other change I snuck in here:

```
# Wait for servers to shutdown
s1.join()
s2.join()
```

Using the saved reference to the `Server`'s accept worker, we call `.join()` from the main thread to force things to block while the servers are running.  Without this, your main program will exit nearly immediately, due to the workers' `.daemon` attribute being set.

It's also worth noting that this approach will have some quirks:

1. Since the handler functions are running in separate processes, you will need to share data structures between them carefully using Queue, Value, Pipe, and other `multiprocessing` constructs if they depend on each other.
2. There is no rate limiting of active concurrent connections; creating a new process for every single request can be expensive, and can create a vector for your service being easily DoSed.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Each instance of `Server` will be completely independent. There will be no data sharing between processes and there will be no more than 2 - 3 clients per server.